# WPF - MVVM Textbox restrict to specific characters

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am trying to make text box accept only specific characters.

My TextBox is bound to the following:

```
    private string _CompanyID;
    public string CompanyID
    {
        get { return _CompanyID; }
        set
        {
            _CompanyID = UniversalHelpers.sReturnCorrectColumnName(value);
            OnPropertyChanged("CompanyID");
        }
    }
```

Where this is the function that is being called:

```
    public static string sReturnCorrectColumnName(string sInput)
    {
        if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(sInput))
            return Regex.Replace(sInput, @"[^a-zA-Z]", string.Empty).ToUpper();
        else
            return sInput;
    }
```

(I am allowing only a-z & A-Z, nothing else).

Finally my TextBox looks like this:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding ExcelBindings.CompanyID, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

What I don't understand is, that user can still write anything he wants, even though my Mode is set to TwoWay.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Yeah, this never works out well.  Implement IDataErrorInfo and/or INotifyDataErrorInfo and just mark the instance errored when they include incorrect characters.

Comment: The UI won't automatically update with changes you've made when the user is typing. It's saved correctly (only a-z & A-Z) but your UI won't automatically update even with TwoWay binding

Comment: Is there a way how to update the UI without registering a new Dependency Property?

Comment: You should use a custom UI element there that restricts the input on the view-side using “classic” solutions like change listeners.

Comment: Use a MaskedTextBox. There is one in the Extended WPF Toolkit

Comment: Are you sure you are binding the DataContext correctly? Put a breakpoint in the setter - is it even being triggered when you enter something in the TextBox? Are there binding errors in the debug output?

Comment: @svinja When you change the value within a setter, the change will not be reflected in the UI, even if you raise the PropertyChanged event, because the UI does not expect you to modify the value that it passed in and will not requery the property

Comment: That is incorrect, it will change if you raise the PropertyChanged event.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You should use a custom UI element there that restricts the input on the view-side using “classic” solutions like change listeners.

For example, you can just create a simple subtype of `TextBox` that overrides the `OnPreviewTextInput` method. There, you can decide when some input should go through, or when you want to prevent it.

For example, this is a custom TextBox that takes only characters from the ASCII alphabet:

```
public class AlphabetTextBox : TextBox
{
    private static readonly Regex regex = new Regex("^[a-zA-Z]+$");

    protected override void OnPreviewTextInput(TextCompositionEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!regex.IsMatch(e.Text))
            e.Handled = true;
        base.OnPreviewTextInput(e);
    }
}
```

Of course, you could also make the regular expression a property of the text box and allow people to set it from XAML. That way, you would get a very reusable component which you can use for various applications.

Answer (score 1):

I do this with the PreviewtextInput event. I have a generic event used for multiple TextBoxes which takes the regex from a configuration table, but I have hard-coded the regex in this example.

```
private void GenericTextBox_PreviewTextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
{
   e.Handled = !IsTextAllowed(e.Text, @"[^a-zA-Z]");
}

private static bool IsTextAllowed(string Text, string AllowedRegex)
{
    try
    {
        var regex = new Regex(AllowedRegex);
        return !regex.IsMatch(Text);
    }
    catch
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, humans type in numbers sequentially, the fools.
To type in "0.1", a legitimate string, you have to type in "0.", which fails.
Also, re the accepted answer from @poke (which is great), the e.Text value is the *change* to the textbox (keystroke).
You must add this change to the current textbox string, and then validate the concatenated candidate string, and see if that is valid.
Humans are also wiley, so they will paste from the clipboard to get around the restriction.
With a textbox, you will never be able to block all garbage in, because at some point the user will have to go through garbage, to get to a valid string.
So you can block illegal character entry using e.Text, or allow sequential step failure.  But you will still have to check the final string for validity too.
Below is an example of a textbox that allows users to type in a decimal value with a max of 8 dec places in, but they could still cheat this by pasting from the clipboard.

```
////////////////////////
// REGEXTEXTBOX CLASS //
////////////////////////


using System.Windows.Controls; // Textbox
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions; // Regex

namespace MyNamespace
{
    public class RegexTextBox : TextBox
    {
        private Regex _regex = null;

        public Regex Regex
        {
            get { return _regex; }
            set { _regex = value; }
        }


        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        // MEMBERS

        protected override void OnPreviewTextInput(TextCompositionEventArgs e)
        {
            var prefix = "OnPreviewTextInput() - ";
            logger.Debug(prefix + "Entering");

            string currentText = this.Text;
            string candidateText = currentText + e.Text;

            // If we have a set regex, and the current text fails,
            // mark as handled so the text is not processed.
            if (_regex != null && !_regex.IsMatch(candidateText))
            {
                e.Handled = true;
            }           

            base.OnPreviewTextInput(e);
        }

    } // end of class RegexTextbox

} // end of MyNamespace


/////////////////////
// MAINWINDOW.XAML //
/////////////////////

//(Window class needs to know your namespace so it needs xmlns:myNamespace="clr-namespace:MyNamespace")

<myNamespace:RegexTextBox 
 x:Name="textboxPayToAmount" 
 Text="{Binding PayToAmount}">
</myNamespace:RegexTextBox> 


////////////////////////
// MAINWINDOW.XAML.CS //
////////////////////////

namespace MyNamespace
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            textboxPayToAmount.Regex = 
                new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"^\d*(\.\d{0,8})?$");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Public Shared Function GetWordCount(str As String) As Integer
    Dim collection As MatchCollection = Regex.Matches(str, "\S+")
    Return collection.Count
End Function

Public Shared Function GetInWordLimit(str As String, max_words As Integer) As String
    Dim final As String = ""
    Dim count As Integer = Core.StringOperations.GetWordCount(str)
    Dim avg_max_length As Integer = max_words * 7

    Dim words = str.Split(" ")
    If (words.Length > max_words - 1 And count > max_words - 1) Then
        Dim index As Integer = 0
        For Each word In words
            If index >= max_words Then Exit For

            final &= word & " "
            If Not (Char.IsSeparator(word) Or Char.IsWhiteSpace(word) Or word = "") Then
                index += 1
            End If

        Next
        final = final.TrimEnd
    Else
        final = str
    End If

    If final.Length > avg_max_length - 1 Then final = final.Substring(0, avg_max_length)

    Return final
End Function
```