# Disable button when text box is empty or blank spaces from xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

As my post suggests, I saw a post here on StackOverflow to disable a button when the TextBox Text is empty from xaml. But the problem is, whenever user presses space without typing any charecters, the button enables. Is it possible to disable the button if there are just blank spaces without any text in the TextBox in the xaml iteself.

```
<TextBox x:Name="txtReasonForChange" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" TextWrapping="Wrap" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"></TextBox>
 <Button x:Name="btnSaveOrSaveAs" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=txtReasonForChange,Path=Text.Length}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Click="btnSaveOrSaveAs_Click"></Button>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Rather than using the button click event, I would prefer an MVVM approach of using the Command property, and supplying a class which implements the [ICommand](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.input.icommand?view=netframework-4.7.2) interface. This class can then indicate whether it is enabled or not, via t he CanExecute and CanExecuteChanged parts of that interface, which will enable and disable the button. However, you are just doing a code behind click event, so...

Add a new converter class. (It is simply a class implementing the [IConverter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2) interface.) Then use the converter in the binding.

```
 // In your converter class, which you could call IsNullOrWhiteSpaceConverter
 public object Convert(object value, Type targetType,
     object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
 {
      var input = (string)value;
      return String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(input);
 }
```

Declare the converter in an appropriate Resources section of the XAML (e.g. for the window or usercontrol) like this:

```
<yourNamespace:IsNullOrWhiteSpaceConverter x:Key="IsNullOrWhiteSpaceConverter" />
```

Then your binding becomes...

```
IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=txtReasonForChange,Path=Text,
    Converter={StaticResource IsNullOrWhiteSpaceConverter}}"
```

Comment: Yea I have written a custom converter to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible to imply only by Xaml.
I have two way to imply  this demand,but they all need code.

1.When you use MVVM,you can disable button through command.
2.Binding button's IsEnable property to Textbox.Text,through a converter to check 
wether  Textbox.Text is only empty character.

Answer (score 1):

Converter seems to be easiest/best mvvm way. 

Id also suggest use simple [custom textbox](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32572768/7701667) which doesnt accept space (customize as needed)

 And disable using triggers~